# How to add an extra field to orders in Magento such as delivery date?

Tags: magento

I need for an order to specify it's delivery date. On the product details page I want to give the customer the ability to specify a delivery date (select the delivery date and then click on the "add to cart" button). In my opinion, it is natural to have an extra field to the order named "delivery date" for example and in the admin page, when i click an order, to be able to see the delivery date. Is there a way do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a new attribute to order EAV and a new column to sales_flat_order field
2. make your observer to set the value to order object before order is saved
3. change order info template to display your variable